# Check image type if renamed from .png to .jpg

Tags: php, image

If it possible to check if the type of image if it was renamed from `.png` to `.jpg`?

**I need this because when I use a resize function my website stop working if the uploaded image was renamed from .png to .jpg (I made my code to accept only .jpg images)**

Comment: what process are you using to resize.  You should look at it and see how its saving the resized image and force it to be `.jpg`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[getimagesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) will contain info about image type:

```
$info = getimagesize('file.png');
if($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_JPEG){

}
```

Answer (score 13):

Every .png starts with these bytes:

```
89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A
```

They are the PNG signature. If a .jpg starts with those bytes, it is not a jpg.

Answer (score 2):

You can always read the image type to check an image using [exif_imagetype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)

```
$image_type = exif_imagetype($filename);
```

Example:

```
<?php
if (exif_imagetype('image.gif') != IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
    echo 'The picture is not a gif';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use this

```
if($_FILES["imagefile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
{

return true;

}

else if($_FILES["imagefile"]["type"] == "image/png")

{

return false;

}
```

Or you should use this mime_content_type is more reliable because the `$_FILES["imagefile"]["type"]` can be faked from client side...

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried it. The image type of renamte .png image is "Image/jpeg"

Answer (score 2):

What you need to know is not the history of the file, but its real format. You can do that by examining the file's content: JPG files should begin with the bytes FF D8 and end with FF D9. PNG files start with a different signature: \211 P N G \r \n \032 \n (in hexadecimal: 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A).

See this website for more information: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29

Answer (score 0):

Try the `file` command.

When `unknownimage` is a JPG image:

```
$ file unknownimage 
unknownimage: JPEG image data, baseline, precision 8, 400x400, frames 3
```

When `unknownimage` file is a PNG image:

```
$ file unknownimage 
unknownimage: PNG image data, 779 x 701, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```