# Detect image type from file path and file name

Tags: php, image, filepath

I'm trying to echo an image from a folder called **avatar_50x50**, with the name of the file being the **username**. Although the extension will always be an image, how will I determine what file type it is?

```
<img src="../images/users/avatar_50x50/<?php echo $sel_user['username']; ?>"
```

Comment: store the name of the image in the db, it's better than searching the image

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check a file path is an image or not in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117396/how-to-check-a-file-path-is-an-image-or-not-in-php)

Comment: I have no table in my database for files. What's the alternative?

Comment: Duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130804/checking-image-file-type) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547113/check-image-type-if-renamed-from-png-to-jpg) and there are certainly more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `glob()` and take first element from array if you are sure there is only one image with name as username:

```
<?php
    $file = glob('../images/users/avatar_50x50/'.$sel_user['username'].'.*');
    echo '<img src="../images/users/avatar_50x50/'.$file[0].'" alt="" />';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http://php.net/exif_imagetype

And than use "switch" operator to find right image ext.

```
$type = exif_imagetype($image);
switch($type) {
  case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
    $ext = '.gif';
  // etc...
}
```